# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando escrever um script e só a primeira parte funciona:

```
import re

with open('lista.csv', 'r') as f:
    primeira_linha = f.readline()
    #print(primeira_linha)
    outras_linhas = f.readlines()
    #print(outras_linhas)
    for linha in outras_linhas:
        coluna = linha.split(";")
        nome = coluna[0]
        idade = coluna[1]
        sexo = coluna[2]
        ano = coluna[3]
        #print (nome)


        #encontrar o nome mais longo da lista
        for x in sorted(nome):
            print ("O nome mais longo é:" + max(nome))

        #nomes que terminam em a 
        for a in nome:
            if a in re.findall("r'(.*)a$"):
                print ("Os nomes que terminam em a sao:" + a)

        #nomes compostos
        for c in nome:
            if c in re.findall("r'(.*)-(.*)"):
                print ("Os nomes compostos sao:" + c)

        #nomes que têm um y
        for y in nome:
            if "y" in nome:
                print ("Os nomes que têm y sao:" + a)

        #nome que mais se repete
        repeticoes = {}
        for r in nome:
            if r in repeticoes:
                repeticoes[r] = repeticoes[r] + 1
            else:
                repeticoes[r] = 1

                print (repeticoes)
```

Além de nenhum `for` funcionar, ainda aparece este erro que não consigo decifrar (imagino que seja tabulação/indentaçao, mas por quê?

> ```
>  File "portugues.py", line 20
>      print ("O nome mais longo é:" + max(nome))
>                                               ^
> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
> ```

Comment: Isso é um problema com o seu editor, não com Python. Você precisa se certificar de que as configurações de TABS estão corretas. Aliás, você usa tabs ou espaços pra indentar o código?

Comment: Verdade, nao ha erro de indentaçao no IDLE do python so no Geany. E sempre uso TABS. Mas meu script ainda nao funciona. Obrigada de qualquer forma (desculpe a falta de acentos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" deve ser por causa de haver incoerência entre espaços e tabs tal como o @jbueno disse em comentário, melhor manter ou sempre espaços, ou sempre tabs.

Quanto a nenhum for estar a funcionar, é porque está a fazer loops dentro de loops e neste contexto não resulta, fiz um exemplo para o ajudar, para isto escusa de importar `re`:

lista.csv:

```
nome;idade;sexo;ano
miguel;30;masculino;1985
pitanga;25;masculino;1990
Sara;20;feminino;1996
Inês;23;feminino;1993
yuri;12;masculino;2004
Sara;40;feminino;1975
```

Código:

```
with open('lista.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    colunas = lines[0].split(';') # na primeira linha temos os nomes das colunas
    params = [] # cada linha (lista) a seguir vai ser guardada dentro de uma lista mae
    for line in lines[1:]: # escusamos de passar pela primeira linha outra vez, já sabemos que sao os nomes das colunas
        params.append(line.split(';')) # guardando cada linha, dados de cada pessoa

# aqui e importante saber a estrutura da variavel params, print(params) para perceber, no indice 0 em cada sublista temos um nome
nome_mais_longo = max((i[0] for i in params), key=len) # vamos saber o nome maior com base no returno da função len
nomes_que_terminam_a = [i[0] for i in params if i[0].endswith('a')] # endswith e um metodo que dá muito jeito para isto, se o nome acaba em 'a'
nomes_com_y = [i[0] for i in params if 'y' in i[0]] # guardamos numa lista os nomes se comecarem com 'y'

contagens_nome = {}
for i in params: 
    contagens_nome[i[0]] = contagens_nome.get(i[0], 0) + 1 # tentamos aceder a chave i[0], nome em que estamos, se nao existir comeca como 0 e somamos 1

nome_que_mais_se_repete = max(i[::-1] for i in contagens_nome.items()) # revertemos cada (chave, valor) de maneira a ficarmos com (valor, chave) para conseguirmos extrair o valor max
#nome_que_mais_se_repete = max(contagens_nome.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]) # esta seria outra maneira de fazer a linha acima  

print(nome_mais_longo)
print(nomes_que_terminam_a)
print(nomes_com_y)
print(nome_que_mais_se_repete)
```

Output:

> pitanga
>   ['pitanga', 'Sara', 'Sara']
>   ['yuri']
>   (2, 'Sara')

Nos comentários do código tento explicar cada linha, leia com atenção.